# Using Structs -- Odd Issue

Tags: c++, struct

Been awhile since I've used structs in C++.

Any idea why this isn't working? My compiler is complaining about DataStruct not being a recognized type but Intellisense in VC++ is still able to see the data members inside the struct so the syntax is ok...

Frustating. xD

```
struct DataStruct
{
    int first;
};



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    DataStruct test;
    //test.first = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you sure you are compiling the file as C++? If you compile it as C (i.e. if the file has a .c rather than a .cpp extension), you will have problems.

Comment: That was it. Was using a template and didn't notice it was .c and not .cpp

Comment: This is my first guess as well. Above code is legit C++ but not legit C.

Comment: Just to clarify : Bobber is talking about VC++ IDE templates and not `template` s in C++.

Comment: Another reason to as a rule typedef structs - then you don't have to worry about whether it'll compile as C or C++ - it'll work in both. Of course, it's always a pretty good idea to know if you're working C or C++, but why not make code work in both if the only downside is a bit more typing (pun intended) that you can probably get your editor to do for you?

Comment: @Michael When I'm writing C++ code, I never expect it to be compilable under C. For example, I normally give structs a constructor. So using a typedef would be pointless.

Comment: @Neil: understood.  I write enough C code (embedded stuff) that 'typedef'ing structs just happens.

Answer (score 4):

You are compiling as C code. C requires you to refer to it using the "Struct" keyword or typedef it. C++ does not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `struct DataStruct` to refer to the struct.

Alternatively, you can typedef it as `DataStruct` if don't want to use the "struct" everywhere.

Comment: This is why instantly accepting the first answer that fixes the problem isn't really a good idea. Often, it misses the point entirely.

Comment: This simply isn't true.   As other people have written, the most likely problem is you've saved your file as a ".c" or are in some other way compiling as C instead of C++.

Comment: The thing is that even if you don't *need* to do it in C++, it doesn't hurt.